# Turn SOCKS to VPN using OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, socks-proxy, socks

I'm on Windows 10 and I have a local SOCKS connection (Psiphon 3) and I want to share this connection via Wifi Hotspot.

I know how to share an OpenVPN connection via wifi hotspot but I don't know how to share a SOCKS connection.

- OpenVPN also supports SOCKS proxy tunneling:
  [OpenVPN SOCKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p9MP.png) 
  Is it possible to make a local server that OpenVPN can connect to and then use the built-in SOCKS proxy feature of OpenVPN?
  This way I will have an Ethernet connection (created by OpenVPN) on my adapters and I can click it's properties and share it via the Wifi Hotspot (built-in feature of Windows 10).
- Another possible way is to make the Wifi-Hotspot (which is called Local Area Connection* 12 on adapter settings in control panel) tunnel through the proxy but I don't know how.
  Same scenario has been asked and answered on [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144562/redirect-all-packets-from-eth1-eth2-through-a-socks-proxy) I hope someone has a solution for Windows.
- Someone suggested that [badvpn on github](https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn) converts SOCKS to VPN but there are no releases for it, it's just a source code and I don't know how to build and use it.
- Connectify Hotspot is capable of sharing SOCKS connections but it's paid, free alternatives seem to not do the job, I tired "MyPublicWifi" and "Lion Scripts Hotspot Creator".